# How to get editable data from custom listview when user click on next button

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

Friends,
  I am developing simple but tricky quiz app through android. Please have a look on attached screenshot. In the screen you can see there are one question & having 3 buttons. R- Rating will be given Img- Camera will take  picture for that question & S- Standard image.
So what i need is, how to get values of all the list items(when user gives rating & take image for question) when i click on Next button which is at the bottom of the listview. Also i want to validate if user has skipped any of the question to answer & want to point out or simply show him dialog with message.
What is the best way to implement

[image: List view]

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to create a class that will be added in your `ListView` each time the user answer a question, and on that class you will have fields for your Rating and Image.

So when you check the `ListView` if it is already populated with answer you can just iterate your array of class that was added in your `ListView`.

You will check this if the user has clicked the `Next Button only.`

```
how to check if the user didnt answer some question?
```

Iterate to your array of class and check the Rating and Image Fields if it is empty, if it is then show dialog and tell the user to answer that unanswered question.